# C# tests with Windows Forms fails on Mono/Travis

Tags: c#, forms, mono, travis-ci

I started [a new project](https://github.com/ashes999/chrysalis). It's a C# class library, and ships with a bunch of windows `Form` classes that the user can use and extend.

I wrote and ran [some unit tests](https://github.com/ashes999/chrysalis/blob/master/Chrysalis.Core.UnitTests/Forms/ChrysalisFormTests.cs) on Windows with NUnit. None of my tests go as far as calling `form.Show()`. The tests all pass with TestDriven.NET on Windows.

When Travis runs my tests under a docker container on Linux, I get an exception stack:

`System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext' threw an exception.
  ----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI' threw an exception.
  ----> System.ArgumentNullException : Could not open display (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable)
Parameter name: Display
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () <0x40965cf0 + 0x0005e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () <0x409656f0 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () <0x40965520 + 0x0002d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () <0x40964bd0 + 0x000ef> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Chrysalis.Core.Forms.ChrysalisForm..ctor () <0x40961790 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Chrysalis.Core.UnitTests.Forms.ChrysalisFormTests+TestChrysalisForm..ctor () <0x40961760 + 0x00014> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Chrysalis.Core.UnitTests.Forms.ChrysalisFormTests+TestChrysalisForm:.ctor ()
  at Chrysalis.Core.UnitTests.Forms.ChrysalisFormTests.CancelButtonMovesWhenResizeEventFires () <0x409614f0 + 0x0003e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x4090c360 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--TypeInitializationException
  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () <0x4096bcb0 + 0x00010> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () <0x40967210 + 0x0001c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () <0x40965cf0 + 0x00274> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () <0x40967100 + 0x00031> in <filename unknown>:0 
--ArgumentNullException
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) <0x4096e400 + 0x00ec7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () <0x4096c210 + 0x00231> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () <0x4096c000 + 0x00081> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () <0x4096bd20 + 0x00170> in <filename unknown>:0`

The build node obviously doesn't have a display, because it's headless.

Is there any way to get my tests to run under this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted this to GitHub (Travis-CI repo) and got an answer from Alexander Köplinger.

Travis supports using `xvfb` as a GUI back-end. I just needed to add this to my `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start
```

The tests then passed.